# How to hook into a method with int[] using xposed?

Tags: java, android, arrays, hook, xposed

I am trying to hook into this method in NotificationManagerService using Xposed:

```
void enqueueNotificationInternal(final String pkg, final String opPkg, final int callingUid,
            final int callingPid, final String tag, final int id, final Notification notification,
            int[] idOut, int incomingUserId)
```

For that I am using this hook:

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService", loadPackageParam.classLoader,
                "enqueueNotificationInternal", String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, String.class,
                Integer.class, Notification.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, new XC_MethodHook(){
//More code...
});
```

However this is giving me an error in the Xposed log that the method could not be found. It is probably because of `int[] idOut`, because I am not sure what the class of that 'type' of that parameter is. Apparently not `Integer.class`, or is it and is something else wrong?

Comment: It appears you are trying to match "final int callingUid" to Integer.class, which is not correct.  You can user Integer.TYPE or int.class for int primitives.

Comment: For idOut, you can do: Class.forName("[I") or you could do  "new int[0].getClass()"

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try it out after school :)

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I replaced Integer.class with int.class, and the integer array with new int[0].class

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was declaring an empty array variable and get its class:

```
int[] data = new int[0];

XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.class", 
    loadPackageParam.classLoader, 
    "methodName", 
    String.class, 
    data.getClass(), 
    new XC_MethodHook(){
        // code
    });
```

Another possible answer:

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.class", 
    loadPackageParam.classLoader, 
    "methodName", 
    String.class, 
    int[].class, 
    new XC_MethodHook(){
        // code
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService", 
    loadPackageParam.classLoader, "enqueueNotificationInternal", String.class, 
    String.class, int.class, int.class, String.class, int.class,
    Notification.class, new int[0].class, int.class, new XC_MethodHook(){
        //More code...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
 int[].class
```

other answers works but are the wrong way.